# Calling derived class instances from a stack of a base class

Tags: c++

Say I have an base struct `Action`:

```
struct Action
{
    int type;
    virtual void print() { }
}
```

And 2 derived structs `A1, A2`:

```
struct A1 : Action
{
    A1 : Action(0) { }
    void print() { cout << "A1"; }
}

struct A2 : Action
{
    A2 : Action(1) { }
    void print() { cout << "A2"; }
}
```

Then in my main function I have a stack:

```
stack<Action> actions;
A1 a1;
A2 a2;
actions.push(a1);
actions.push(a2);

while(!actions.empty())
{
    Action element = actions.top();
    element.print();
    actions.pop();
}
```

However, the `print()` function will always call the base class `print()`, instead of the derived class. How do I get it to refer to the derived class instead?

In C# I understand there is a `GetType()` function, but is there a similar thing in c++?

Edit: Specifically I am looking for a way to collect all objects of a similar base class into a single container, so that I can iterate through all of them, without losing information of a derived class.

Something along the lines of (in C#):

```
if(element.getType() == typeof(A1))
    ((A1)element).print();
else if (element.getType() == typeof(A2))
    ((A2)element).print();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Short answer: you need to use (smart) pointers or references for polymorphism. The [`typeid` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) would be roughly the equivalent of C# `GetType()` but it won't help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `actions.push(a1);` and `Action element = actions.top();` you are actually storing and getting **copies** of the actual `Action` that you want to store. To take advantage of [`virtual functions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) you need to access the members through **pointers or references**.

In your example, you would need to:

1. Store pointers to your Actions

   ```
   stack<Action*> actions;
   A1 a1;
   A2 a2;
   actions.push(&a1);
   actions.push(&a2);
   ```
2. Get those pointers and access `print` through them:

   ```
   while(!actions.empty())
   {
       Action* element = actions.top();
       element->print();
       actions.pop();
   }
   ```

   [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/054e05ff46f3fa78).

---

It would be preferable to use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of a raw one but I omitted the details for the sake of simplicity.